# Control image texture source from outside node group

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders

I'm working on turning a cavity node setup I found online into a node group I can append to my blender files.

The setup uses several mapping nodes (that I already converted to math nodes so the values can be controlled from outside the group), but now I need image textures that receive the modified UV coordinates for the normal map (the "NormalTest.png" nodes in the image below).

[image: Node setup]

The problem is that I want to control the image source from outside the node group and I don't know how to do that. Is there a node that can receive an image as a color input and output an image with the mapping applied? Or is there a way to control the image source from outside the node group?

Comment: If you have same image for every mapping node, then you can put it in another group and create a copy outside of main group for quick access

Comment: But the problem is every mapping node has a different location value and the value itself can't be controlled from the outside.